# How can I make these QuickTime video files with damaged/missing headers playable?

Tags: file, video, quicktime

I have a bunch of QuickTime movies that were created before the Mac OS X days, likely on OS 8 and 9. They don't play anymore in any video player I try (QuickTime, VLC, various other Linux players). The files don't seem to have headers, as the `file` command says they're just data:

```
$ file ~/Desktop/An\ Ordinary\ Car.mov 
~/Desktop/An Ordinary Car.mov: data
```

I suspect that all the actual image data is there because the file size on these is large enough:

```
$ ls -lh ~/Desktop/An\ Ordinary\ Car.mov 
-rw-------@ 1 <name>  staff    30M May  1  2002 ~/Desktop/An Ordinary Car.mov
```

Since the video is in there somewhere, and I know that it's a QuickTime movie, is there any way I can repair the file's header (or whatever) to make video players understand how to play it?

Comment: Can you give a link to one of the video files?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5uw2bbelt8g4iy7/Mining%20Platform.mov?dl=0

Comment: Ok - a quick look with ffprobe show that it see the moov atom (the header part of the file) is missing: '[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fa902004600] moov atom not found'. There are some instructions here about how you might be able to recover from this: http://superuser.com/q/417100

Comment: If you do find the needed resource fork files as explained in @Rolf's excellent answer, then you will be able to "flatten" your movies using Quicktime 7 on a Mac. If you have many files to process, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68020330/111036) for a scripted/automated way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

MacOS Classic typically used to store movies with the movie header (moov atom) in the file's resource fork and the movie data (mdat atom) ie. the media essence itself in the data fork, unless they were "flattened" to store the complete movie in a single fork. Originally movies had to be explicitly flattened so they could be opened on Windows but with Mac OS X Apple started creating flattened movies by default. Storing the movie header in the resource fork became deprecated - precisely because of the sort of issues you're now seeing where you might lose the resource fork.

When saving files containing a resource fork to volumes that don't support multiple forks (eg. FAT32) the resource fork was written to a file starting ._  so you might have File.mov and ._File.mov.

You need to go back to your source disks or backups and try to find the original files complete with resource forks otherwise the movies won't open. With very few exceptions (the only one I can think of is DV, where the data fork is just a .dv stream that other apps can play) the data fork won't contain enough information to say where the data for each frame starts; for that you need the sample table in the movie header.